# Backbone model not updating with server data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone, and I can't figure out this issue.

Here's my model:

```
var itinerary = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
      return {
        ItineraryID: null,
        ItineraryString: "No itineraries",
        CreatorID: null,
        PublicFlag: false,
        CreateDate: null,
        LastUpdate: null
      }
    },
    urlRoot:'/dev/api/itineraries',
    idAttribute:'ItineraryID'
});
```

Here's my code fetching a given itinerary from the server:

```
function show_saved_itinerary(tripID) {
    //Get itinerary from database
    var savedTrip = new itinerary({ItineraryID:tripID});

    savedTrip.fetch();
    thisTrip = savedTrip.get('ItineraryString');
}
```

I get the proper response from the server, but the "get('ItineraryString')" line returns the default value -- "No  itineraries" -- instead  of the bit fetched from the server.

After fetching, the model looks like this:

```
({
    cid:"c1",
    attributes:{
        0:{
            ItineraryID:"21",
            ItineraryString:"44.8582569~-93.32529540000002~second sushi test~ChIJ7w_kLSDY94cRYTNjiDPPJa8",
            CreatorID:"1",
            PublicFlag:"0",
            CreateDate:"1412964129",
            LastUpdate:"2014-10-13 12:58:57"
        },
        ItineraryID:"21",
        ItineraryString:"No itineraries",
        CreatorID:null,
        PublicFlag:false,
        CreateDate:null,
        LastUpdate:null
    },
        _changing:false,
        _previousAttributes:{ItineraryID:"21", ItineraryString:"No itineraries", CreatorID:null, PublicFlag:false, CreateDate:null, LastUpdate:null},
        changed:{0:{ItineraryID:"21", ItineraryString:"44.8582569~-93.32529540000002~second sushi test~ChIJ7w_kLSDY94cRYTNjiDPPJa8", CreatorID:"1", PublicFlag:"0", CreateDate:"1412964129", LastUpdate:"2014-10-13 12:58:57"}},
        id:"21",
        _pending:false
})
```

So it's adding the server data to the model inside the "0:" attribute.

But how do I get it to replace the default values so a simple model.get() call will return the right values?

Comment: You have to show the response from your server

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your JSON response is actually an array of JSON objects, in which case you will need to parse the response before adding it to the model by adding a parse method to your model definition.

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
... 
 parse : function(resp){
    return resp[0];
 },
});
```

Comment: No, the response isn't an array of JSON objects. Here's what the response looks like:

`[{"ItineraryID":"21","ItineraryString":"44.8582569~-93.32529540000002~second sushi test~ChIJ7w_kLSDY94cRYTNjiDPPJa8","CreatorID":"1","PublicFlag":"0","CreateDate":"1412964129","LastUpdate":"2014-10-13 12:58:57"}]`

Comment: @SteveRay `[]` denote arrays. What you posted is a json array with 1 object. If you try what I answered, you will see that it works.

Comment: I added it, it still returns the default values. Model looks like this:

`var itinerary = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: function() {
    return {
   ItineraryID: null,
   ItineraryString: "No itineraries",
   CreatorID: null,
   PublicFlag: false,
   CreateDate: null,
   LastUpdate: null
    }
  },
  parse : function(resp){
   return resp[0];
  },
   urlRoot:'/dev/api/itineraries',
  idAttribute:'ItineraryID'
 });`