# Backbone Models not updating after Sinon.fakeServer responds to model.fetch

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jestjs, sinon, synchronous

I am attempting to write a test suite for our Backbone app. We are using Jest as the testing framework, and Sinon for server mocking.

An example test looks like

**device.test.js**

```
describe('API integration', ()=>{
        let response = {"data": {
                "attributes": {
                    "created_at": "2018-06-14T07:05:14.919Z",
                },
                "id": "234",
                "type": "device"
         }};

        let server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
        afterAll(() => {
            server.restore();
        });

        let device = new Device({
            id: '234'
            created_at: null,
            agent_code: null,
            device_code: null,
        });

        server.respondWith('GET',
            'api/device/234',
            [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            JSON.stringify(response)]);

        device.fetch();
        server.respond();
        it('fetches to the right URL', ()=>{
            // these both pass
            expect(server.requests[0].method === 'GET');
            expect(server.requests[0].url === 'api/device/234');
        });
        it('updates its fields properly after a fetch', ()=>{
           // this test fails
           expect(device.get('created_at')).toBe(response.attributes.created_at);

        });           
    });
```

I was using [this article](https://tinnedfruit.com/articles/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon-2.html) as an example of how to test backbone models with sinon (scroll towards nearly the bottom for fakeserver usage) as well as using the [sinon fakeserver docs](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.0.0/fake-xhr-and-server/).

According to what I've read, `server.respond()` should evaluate all async requests, and thus the models should be updated synchronously. That is to say, my expectation is that any references to `device` after `server.respond` should be referring to a post-fetch `device` model. My expectation is not met - after a call to `server.respond()`, `device.get('created_at')` remains `undefined`. This is not the case in production, when our app is running.

Just in case, I tried to throw tests into a `{success: function(){}}` callback, as well as in `.then` and `.done`, but then the tests wouldn't run, nor would `console.log()` or any other debugging efforts.

**How can I test asynchronous methods such as `Backbone.model.fetch()` in Jest using Sinon.fakeServer?**

EDIT: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368140/backbone-model-not-updating-with-server-data) made me wonder if maybe `parse` was even being called - perhaps I am structuring my return data abnormally. Parse is indeed being called, so now I suspect this is not an issue with asynchronousness, but instead with how I am structuring my data in the `response` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that `id` property of my model was mis-matched with the `id` property of the response object from my API_MOCKS helper file. It has nothing to do with asynch.